# Class not calling paintEvent method

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, paintevent

My application uses two classes and therefore has 2 class "files".

- First class displays buttons etc.
- Second class draws rectangles, and upon a keypress, it should change the color of certain rectangles (by redrawing them).

The second class contains a `paintEvent` method. The program compiles fine, however the rectangles do not show, and I make a test method that should exit the app, however that doesn't work either.

First class, which is called in main.cpp:

```
#include "RCcar.h"
#include "renderArea.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>

RCcar::RCcar()
{
    Renderarea = new renderArea;
    Renderarea->test();
    //Renderarea->update();
    exit = new QPushButton("Exit", this);
    exit->setGeometry(410, 440, 80, 50);
    connect(exit, SIGNAL(released()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));
    setFixedSize(500, 500);
}

#pragma once

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;
class renderArea;
class RCcar : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RCcar();
private:
    QPushButton *exit;
    renderArea *Renderarea;
};
```

Second class, which is created in class `RCcar`:

```
#include "renderArea.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

renderArea::renderArea(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    setFixedSize(40, 40);
    //this->update();
}

void renderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    QRect a = QRect(90, 230, 70, 40);
    QRect s = QRect(215, 230, 70, 40);
    QRect d = QRect(340, 230, 70, 40);
    QRect w = QRect(215, 150, 70, 40);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.drawText(a, Qt::AlignCenter, "a");
    painter.drawText(s, Qt::AlignCenter, "s");
    painter.drawText(d, Qt::AlignCenter, "d");
    painter.drawText(w, Qt::AlignCenter, "w");
    painter.drawRect(a);
    painter.drawRect(s);
    painter.drawRect(d);
    painter.drawRect(w);
}

void renderArea::test() {
    QApplication::instance()->quit();
}

#pragma once
#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;
class renderArea : public QWidget 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum Keys {w,a,s,d};
    renderArea(QWidget *parent=0);
    void test();
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
private:
    Keys keys;
    QPushButton *button;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the `RCcar` widget be a parent to the `renderArea` widget? Perhaps you should set it up as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, there are 2 errors:

1. Since you are not going to use layouts, you must pass `renderArea` the widget as parent, so that it is drawn in the latter.
2. The second is that in the `renderArea` constructor you are setting a size of 40 * 40, and when you draw in the `paintEvent` method you are drawing out of that space.

Corrections are passed as parent to `this` and set an appropriate size.

```
Renderarea = new renderArea(this);
Renderarea->setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 400);
exit = new QPushButton("Exit", this);
exit->setGeometry(410, 440, 80, 50);
connect(exit, SIGNAL(released()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));
setFixedSize(500, 500);
```

And delete the line `setFixedSize(40, 40);`:

```
renderArea::renderArea(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

*Note*: The paintEvent method had been called but drew in an inappropriate space.